# Finding a CodeProject Article on Preventing Processes From Spawning Using .NET Code

Tags: c#, winapi, process, hook

I remember coming across an article on I think CodeProject quite some time ago regarding an antivirus or antimalware some guy was writing where he hooked into the Windows API to be able to catch whenever a new process was started and was prompting he user before allowing the process to start.

I can no longer find the article, and would actually like to be able to implement something like this.  Currently, we have a custom browser built on Gecko that we've integrated access restrictions to sites based on our internal employee security levels, etc.  We prevent any other browser from running with a timer and a call to Process.GetProcessesByName() from a list of the browsers we don't allow.

What we want to accomplish is, instead of just blocking these browsers, where there is a small delay between the other browser starting and it being killed by our service, we'd like to be able to display a dialog instead of the process launching at all, explaining that the program isn't in the allowed list.  This way, we can generate a list of "allowed" processes and just block everything else (we haven't yet had a problem with outside apps being installed, but you can never be too careful).

Unfortunately, we don't do much Windows API programming from C#, so I'm not sure where to begin looking for what calls we need to hook.

Even just a starting point of what to read up on would be helpful.

Comment: [AppLocker and WDAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/wdac-and-applocker-overview) might be a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean this article: [Hooking the native API and controlling process creation on a system-wide basis](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/soviet_protector.aspx)

Comment: I bow to your Google skills sir.  It is late and don't know how I missed this.

Comment: If someone wants, the original page was deleted, you can find it here: http://web.archive.org/web/20090326083419/http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/soviet_protector.aspx?